# Is there a way where my users could be subscribed to a list without a confirmation mail?

Tags: php, symfony, mailchimp

I have integrated **Hype mailchimp** with **Symfony2**,
When a user subscribes to my website, he/she gets a confirmation mail from mailchimp which asks if they want to subscribe to a particular list or not.

Is there a setting in mailchimp or a switch/config setting in the bundle from which I could switch off this confirmation mail and my users could directly be added to the list.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: http://kb.mailchimp.com/article/can-i-shut-off-the-e-mail-that-asks-people-for-confirmation-that-they-want-/ <- googled it!

Comment: 'turn off email confirmation mailchimp' that was what I wrote - not sure how you didn't find it!

Comment: @GrahamRitchie I don't think the "Final “Welcome” Email" in your link is the same as the confirmation email Mayank is talking about.

Answer (score 3):

You have to use the Mailchimp API if you want to subscribe users to a list without a confirmation email.

If you look at the [documentation for list subscribe](http://apidocs.mailchimp.com/api/2.0/lists/subscribe.php), you can set the `double_optin` value to `false`, and your users won't get a confirmation email.

edit:

You could try this code.

```
$merge_vars = array('mc_notes'=> array('test notes'));
$result = $mailchimp->lists->subscribe($listid,
                                    array('email'=>"email@example.com"),
                                    $merge_vars,
                                    false,
                                    true,
                                    false,
                                    false
                                   );
```

Comment: $data = $mailchimp->getList()->addMerge_vars(array('mc_notes' => array('test notes'),'double_optin' => false,'send_welcome' => false))->subscribe($email);

I did this and still am getting a confirmation mail.
Kindly advice!

Comment: I am not asking for the mail which is sent after the user is subscribed, i.e. final welcome email but the mail which asks the user for confirmation.

Comment: Yeah, this should be the mail that asks for confirmation, not the final welcome email. I've added code.

Comment: Not working! :( :(

Still getting a mail that asks for confirmation.

Comment: Can you paste all the code you're using, as well as any errors, and the value of `$result`?

Answer (score 0):

Inside the Mailchimp Class find a function given below and change the  `$double_optin=true`  to `$double_optin=false`

```
function listSubscribe($id, $email_address, $merge_vars=NULL, $email_type='html',
$double_optin=true, $update_existing=false, $replace_interests=true,
$send_welcome=false) {
```

Comment: $data = $mailchimp->getList()->addMerge_vars(array('mc_notes' => array('test notes'),'double_optin' => false,'send_welcome' => false))->subscribe($email);

I did this and still am getting a confirmation mail.
Kindly advice!